# How do I get UITableViewCell to initialize correctly in Application Tests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` and `NSMutableArray`. The array will become the data source for the UITableView. I am trying to create tests for this view controller and am having difficulties. Setting breakpoints and stepping through, the `UITableView` property is `null`. I did call `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` in `setUp`. Here is my code and the explanation to follow:

```
@implementation IouViewControllerTests

- (void)setUp {
    self.iouViewController = [[IouViewController alloc] init];

    Person *person = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"Oky" oweItems:[NSMutableArray array]];
    Iou *iouOne = [[Iou alloc] initWithType:@"lend" amount:[NSDecimalNumber one] note:@"1st iou"];
    Iou *iouTwo = [[Iou alloc] initWithType:@"lend" amount:[NSDecimalNumber one] note:@"2nd iou"];
    [person.iouList addObject:iouOne];
    [person.iouList addObject:iouTwo];

    NSMutableArray *persons = [NSMutableArray array];
    [persons addObject:person];
    self.iouViewController.iouTableArray = persons;

    [self.iouViewController viewDidLoad];
    [self.iouViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.iouViewController.iouTableView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    self.iouViewController = nil;
}

-(void)testViewDidLoad {
    STAssertNotNil(self.iouViewController.view, @"iouViewController view should not be nil");
}

- (void)testCustomCell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.iouViewController.iouTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    STAssertEqualObjects(cell.personName, @"Oky", @"cell name should be right");
}
```

1. Alloc and init the view controller. It uses a NIB file but that implementation is hidden in `-init`.
2. Create the person object and add 2 IOU object to that person.
3. I add that person to the `iouTableArray` which is the data source for the `UITableView`. The `UITableView` takes an array of persons and displays them in the view.
4. Calls `viewDidLoad`, etc and set the `delegate` (correctly?)
5. call `testViewDidLoad` passes
6. call `testCustomCell`. Create an `NSIndex` that will fetch the first row from the `UITableView`. The `CustomCell` subclass the `UITableViewCell` and have the property `personName` as a `UILabel`.

Looking back at the code, I should call `cell.personName.text` to get the name string. However, the error I get is that `cell.personName` is `null`. Stepping through, I see that `iouTableView = (UITableView *) 0x00000000` which I think means null.

What can I do to test the cells in my `UITableView` and get it to work?

PS: I did some reading and there are a lot of materials on mocking objects. They look complicated but I will learn it if I have to. Is there an Apple-recommended way to go about doing what I want to?

Thanks.